# Waiting for web call to finish before continuing code in Unity3d

Tags: c#, web-services, unity-game-engine

I've read many articles but I don't seem to get it. I have this code working now because I hardcode a 3 second delay so there is enough time for the web call to finish so when the score is displayed there is data. But what I really want is to have the web call finish and THEN display the score. Help ?

```
 IEnumerator Start()
{
    client = new MobileServiceClient(_appUrl, _appKey);
    table = client.GetTable<Highscore>("Highscores");
    yield return StartCoroutine(ReadItems());
    DisplayScores();
}

void Update()
{

}

public void btn_GoBack()
{
    Application.LoadLevel("StartScene");
}

private void OnReadItemsCompleted(IRestResponse<List<Highscore>> response)
{
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnReadItemsCompleted data: " + response.Content);
        List<Highscore> items = response.Data;
        Debug.Log("Read items count: " + items.Count);
        Scores = items;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Error Status:" + response.StatusCode + " Uri: " + response.ResponseUri);
    }
}

private IEnumerator ReadItems()
{
    table.Read<Highscore>(OnReadItemsCompleted);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
}

private void DisplayScores()
{
    txtHighScores.text = "";
    int numberOfScores = Math.Min(Scores.Count, 5);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfScores; i++)
    {
        string name = Scores[i].username.ToString();
        string score = Scores[i].score.ToString();

        txtHighScores.text += (i + 1).ToString() + ". " +
                              " - " + name + "\r\n" +
                              score.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is important to pass a parameter with Startcorutine method,
Otherwise it gives error.
So try my fix in your code.

```
 IEnumerator Start()
{
    client = new MobileServiceClient(_appUrl, _appKey);
    table = client.GetTable<Highscore>("Highscores");
    yield return StartCoroutine(ReadItems(2.0f)); //delay
    DisplayScores();
}

IEnumerator ReadItems(float delay)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    table.Read<Highscore>(OnReadItemsCompleted);

}
```

Comment: But I don't want a delay. I want the function COMPLETE (that calls the web service) and not to continue until it is complete.. The delay works but it is a hack

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the method call for "`DisplayScores()`" from `Start()`
2. And insert `DisplayScores()` as the last line of method callback `OnReadItemsCompleted`
3. And then you should remove the line `yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);`

Comment: That gives an error regarding trying to do UI on the non UI thread (or something) ... I find simple having a infinite while loop that checks for non null in Scores works

Comment: In that case
1. Check if there is a callback from the class, which is asynchronous.